# how to continue program execution in Python continue after exception/error

Tags: python-3.x, testing, exception

I am a teacher of python programming. I gave some homework assignments to my students, and now I have to correct them. The homework are submitted as functions. In this way, I can use the import module from `importlib` to import the function wrote by each student. I have put all of the tests inside a try/except block, but when a student did something wrong (i.e., asked for user input, wrong indentation, etc.) the main test program hangs, or stops.

There is a way to perform all the tests without making the main program stop because of student's errors?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Python looks for errors in two-passes.

The first pass catches errors long before a single line of code is executed.

The second pass will only find mistakes at run-time.

try-except blocks will not catch incorrect indentation.

```
try:
    x = 5
    for x in range(0, 9):
    y = 22
    if y > 4:
    z = 6
except:
    pass
```

You get something like:

```
File "D:/python_sandbox/sdfgsdfgdf.py", line 6
    y = 22
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

You can use the `exec` function to execute code stored in a string.

```
with open("test_file.py", mode='r') as student_file:
    lines = student_file.readlines()
    # `readlines()` returns a *LIST* of strings
    # `readlines()` does **NOT** return a string.
    big_string = "\n".join(lines)
    try:
        exec(big_string)
    except BaseException as exc:
        print(type(exc), exc)
```

If you use `exec`, the program will not hang on indentation errors.
`exec` is very dangerous.

A student could delete all of the files on one or more of your hard-drives with the following code:

```
import os
import shutil
import pathlib

cwd_string = os.getcwd()
cwd_path = pathlib.Path(cwd_string)
cwd_root = cwd_path.parts[0]

def keep_going(*args):
    # keep_going(function, path, excinfo)
    args = list(args)
    for idx, arg in enumerate(args):
        args[idx] = repr(str(arg))
    spacer = "\n" + 80*"#" + "\n"
    spacer.join(args)

shutil.rmtree(cwd_root, ignore_errors=True, onerror=keep_going)
```

What you are trying to do is called "***unit testing***"

There is a [python library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#module-unittest) for ***unit testing***.

Ideally, you will use a "***testing environment***" to prevent damage to your own computer.

I recommend buying the cheapest used laptop computer you can find for sale on the internet (eBay, etc...). Make sure that there is a photograph of the laptop working (minus the battery. maybe leave the laptop plugged-in all of time.

Use the cheap laptop for testing students' code.

You can overwrite the built-in `input` function.
That can prevent the program from hanging...

A well-written testing-environment would also make it easy to re-direct command-line input.

```
def input(*args, **kwargs):
    return str(4)

def get_user_input(tipe):
    prompt = "please type in a(n) " + str(tipe) + ":\n"
    while True:
        ugly_user_input = input(prompt)
        pretty_user_input = str(ugly_user_input).strip()
        try:
            ihnt = int(pretty_user_input)
            return ihnt
        except BaseException as exc:
            print(type(exc))
            print("that's not a " + str(tipe))

get_user_input(int)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I have a cheap laptop, so I'll use is for the tests;). Actually, I was seeing how to use something like pytest to perform the homework correction. I will let you know how I'll do!